# Override non-virtual function for testing purpose

Tags: c++, tdd, overriding, virtual, cppunit

I have a class that I need to mock but the class has non-virtual method that needs to mocked. A simplistic version of my problem is demonstrated below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Base{
   public:
    void getNext(){
        cout<<"Base Func"<<endl;
    }
};

class Derived: public Base{
   public:
    void getNext(){
        cout<<"Derived func"<<endl;
    }
};

int main(){
   Base *ptr = new Derived();
   ptr->getNext();
}
```

The above code will call the Base class's "getNext" function but i want it call somehow the derived class's. Real problem is that I have created a new class whose only public method does some logic and also requires a sequence from database. The class (call it DlSequence) that is fetching the sequence from database is base code of our application (core or product you may call) and I cannot change it. And now I need to test my class using cppunit. So, I have to mock or fake the DlSequence class and override the getNext function but this function is not virtual. Is it possible to mock it ? Or can i bypass this problem with any workaround.
I'm not using any mocking framework but I have mockpp installed in my box, I cannot install any other mocking framework. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note: `new` is unnecessary here, polymorphism does not require dynamic allocation.

Comment: Why not use a Derived* to the new Derived instance, rather than a Base*, or am I missing something?

Comment: @Merlin069: probably because the stuff to test takes either a `Base*` or `Base&`, since `Derived` is only created for mock purposes.

Comment: Can you make your class `template` which take `Base` in real code and `MockedBase` in your tests ?

Comment: @Jarod42: Template is a very nice idea, I'm pushing my team to adopt it since it solves the problem very elegantly. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer: **no**.

If the author of the class did not provide a way to customize the behavior, then it is just not possible.

If you cannot change it yourself, bring up the problem with them that you need a hook.

---

The long answer:

In terms of C++ there are probably ways to try and hack around it, but it will be both unsafe and brittle. Off the top of my head I could think of injecting a `virtual` keyword in the base class based on preprocessor hackery or even using LD_PRELOAD to override the function symbol... but honestly, neither is appealing.

*Note: if we are talking about testing your code, and you can change your code, then of course you can create a wrapper around this `Base` thing and make it `virtual`/`template`/whatever; I suppose here that you cannot.*

In terms of SQL however, you might have a chance, for example by redirecting the API calls or even the network calls to either a mock or a database instance under your control. Not knowing the specifics of your system however I cannot advise any further.

Comment: Another unappealing idea that may or may not work depending on a bunch of factors is to link against a different implementation of Base::getNext() in the test project.

Comment: @dlf: That's actually what the `LD_PRELOAD` is about (which is Unix specific), you first load a library with a couple "hack" symbols (such as `Base::getNext()`) and when you next load the real library it will not replace existing symbols, thus you successfully interposed yours (but only a few).

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Thanks, I understood short and long answers. I can create a wrapper over Base in my code and make it virtual, I was avoiding it to know if the problem can be solved in some other way also.

Answer (score 0):

When you're test-driving code that needs to interact with external resources (e.g., third-party libraries, I/O, etc.), you generally [introduce a seam](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=359417&seqNum=2) at which you can mock out the dependency.

This also applies to your situation. If you are unable to modify the code of the collaborator, then it is not much different from a 3rd party library (in that sense). Instead of trying to mock the collaborator directly, identify a seam between your code and the problematic code.

For example:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>

    using namespace std;

    class Base{
    public:
        void getNext(){
            cout << "Base Func" << endl;
        }
    };

    class Seam{
    public:
        virtual ~Seam() { }

        virtual void getNext() = 0;
    };

    class MockCollaborator : public Seam{
    public:
        void getNext(){
            cout << "Derived func" << endl;
        }
    };

    class RealCollaborator : public Seam{
    public:
        void getNext(){
            Base base;
            base.getNext();
        }
    };

    int main(){
        Seam* ptr = new MockCollaborator();
        ptr->getNext();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can make your class template, you can use something like the following:

```
class Base {
public:
    void getNext() { cout << "Base Func" << endl; }
};

// Has the same interface of Base
class MockedBase {
public:
    void getNext() { cout << "Derived func" << endl; }
};
```

And in your class, do something like:

```
template <typename T> class myClass
{
public:
    void callGetNext() { base.getNext(); }
private:
    T base;
};
```

And so use `myClass<Base>` in real code, and `myClass<MockedBase>` in unittest.

Comment: Thanks, template is a nice idea.